# How to get values using QBXML request

Tags: quickbooks

I want to fetch

```
Date Last Sold
MTD Sold
Last Month Sold
YTD Sold
Last Year Sold
Date Last Purchased
```

For Items in `Quickbooks`.

I am using `PHP SDK` to fetch Items from `quickbooks` and able to get them.

But I want to fetch these fields also.

Is there any `QBXML` request I can use to get these fields values for Items ?

Comment: You will probably need to use one of the report. Either the GeneralReport or CustomReport.  Figure out which report you can get the information from in the UI and then see if it is available in one of these 4 types of reports.

Answer (score 2):

As William said already, none of this information is available via direct queries.

You should poke around in the QuickBooks GUI and find out where you can get this information from - it will most likely have to be from a report.

Once you know which report you can get the information from, use the [QuickBooks desktop API reference](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop) to look up the syntax for the specific report type.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<CustomSummaryReportQueryRq>
<CustomSummaryReportType>CustomSummary</CustomSummaryReportType>
 ... etc. etc. etc.
```

You'll get back an XML document which you can parse.

Again, the first step is you need to go find out what report you can get that info from in the GUI.

Comment: The links here seem outdated, you can find the docs for the request here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/generalsummaryreportquery and https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/generaldetailreportquery

Comment: Link in the answer has been updated now. Thanks!